# Pulley problem, wrong decomposition of forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

The mass of the red block is $M$. The rope is inextensible and its mass isn't relevant. The mass of the sphere is $M\sqrt{2}$. The angle between the rope and the horizontal is $45°$. 
[image: image of the problem]
I'm looking for the acceleration of the body but I'm doing something wrong. I want to understand my mistake.

Well, let's say that $\vec{F_m}$ is the force of the rope (the weight of the sphere). We can decompose it as $\vec{F_{mx}}$ and $\vec{F_{my}}$.

$\vec{F_{p}}$ is the weight of the block.

We arrive that $|\vec{F_{my}}|=|\vec{F_{p}}|$ and this is 100% true, in fact the test asks me to demonstrate it. So there is no friction. Then the only force remained is $\vec{F_{mx}}$. So we can calculate the acceleration in this way:

$a = |\vec{F_{mx}}|/M = Mgcos(45)\sqrt{2}/M=g$

However this isn't the solution, so there is a force which I'm not considerating. The solution in fact is $4.03 m/s^2$

EDIT: The question isn't a duplicate: we're talking about acceleration.

Comment: The forces in a static case and a dynamic case are different.  If the system is accelerating, you can't assume the tension on the rope is equal to the weight of the sphere (because the sphere must have unequal forces on it).

Comment: @BowlOfRed but at the beginning the cube isn't accelerating

Comment: An object doesn't have to be moving to accelerate. When you release the system from rest, there is a moment where the setup looks at rest but that doesn't mean the system is not accelerating.

Comment: @Mitchell And what accelerates here? The sphere of course, but should I consider the cube too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving vectors along axes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276786/resolving-vectors-along-axes)

Comment: @sammygerbil The issue in this question is not about force component resolving. It rather seems to be about when something is or isn't accelerating. This is no duplicate of what you refer to.

Comment: I stopped at $|\vec{F_{my}}| = |\vec{F_p}|$  This does not appear to be true.

Comment: @garyp you're right

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the tension present in the rope to be T.
So, for the sphere,
$$M\sqrt2g - T = M\sqrt2a_1$$
Similarly, for the block,
$$\frac{T}{\sqrt2} = Ma_2$$
[Here, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the acceleration of sphere and block respectively.]
Now, assuming that the rope remains taut, the components of $a_1$ and $a_2$ along the rope wouybe equal.
Thus,
$$a_1=\frac{a_2}{\sqrt2}$$
On solving, you should probably reach to the correct answer.
What mistake you were making is 
$$\vec{|F_p|} = \frac{T}{\sqrt2}$$
However, this won’t be the case.
The correct equation I think would be
$$\vec{|F_p|} = \frac{T}{\sqrt2} + N$$
Where N is the force exerted by the ground in contact on the block

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that $F_m$ is set equal to $M\sqrt{2}g$.

This would be the case if the ball was stationary; if it was hanging there without falling, without accelerating. But it *is* in fact accelerating.

When you let go, the ball and box *start* to move. Gravity accelerates the ball downwards. They may not be moving in the very first initial moment, but they still accelerate. Otherwise they would never gain any speed.

Now, go back to where you found the value of $F_m$. I assume you found that by setting up $M\sqrt{2}g-F_m=0$ with Newton's 1st law on the ball. And then you correctly assumed that this $F_m$ pulls all the way along the string to the box. Since we now realized that Newton's 1st law isn't valid here, when the ball isn't stationary, we must instead use Newton's 2nd law and include the missed acceleration term:

$$M\sqrt{2}g-F_m=M\sqrt{2}a_{ball}$$

Comment: @ steeven : tell me one thing that "is accelaration of ball and that of the block  is same in magnitude or different" . i just want to know what is relationship between accelaraion of the ball and accelaration of block .please

Comment: The rope follows the sphere. Their accelerations are equal yes.

Comment: @veereshpandey The acceleration of the ball and box are not necessarily equal. You will find their relationship by calculating what Curio has done in his question, just with the correction I have tried describe here in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid answering questions by looking at the results you are trying to obtain.

Start from the very beginning, without any prior knowledge of the acceleration and tension. All you know is the mass of the objects and the inclination of the rope. This eliminates the factuality of the $\vec F_{p}+\vec F_{my}=0$ relation in the question. This relation might show up in our answer but its not stated true in the question.

Since we are trying to find the acceleration of the block horizontally, begin with finding the acceleration of the rope itself by resolving the weight of the block along the rope to get the acceleration of the block ***along*** the rope and setting up equations of motion for both the objects. After calculating, you are one (or two) manipulation away from your answer.

Comment: @Curio Yes the cube accelerates too if there is a net force acting on it (regardless of its state of motion). I'll leave the calculation to you.

Comment: <<Try to avoid answering questions by looking at the results you are trying to obtain.>>
Never done that

Comment: @veeresh You called ${a_1}$ the acceleration of the sphere but you called ${v_1}$ the horizontal velocity of the block, which on differentiating will give the x component of the acceleration of the rope. To find the real ${a_1}$ you will need the y component too since the rope's acceleration and the sphere's acceleration are the same.

Comment: @Curio I have edited the error again.

Comment: I'm not sure the question can be solved this way, you may need to take a normal force from the (assumed frictionless) surface in to account too. If we may assume the the surface is frictionless, conservation of energy may be more useful.